# Abel's original proof of quintic equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the original proof of Abel-ruffini for the insolvability theorem of quintic equation.
I can not follow the logic in the paper at many steps.
I will ask my doubts in different posts (if that is ok to moderators). 
It is written in the paper that if $$AY^5+BY^4+CY^3+DY^2+EY+F=0......(2)$$
'is solvable  by radicals then,
$$Y=a+bR^{1/5}+cR^{2/5}+dR^{3/5}+eR^{4/5}.......(1)$$
He proves it by saying that   $$v=F/G = f+g^{1/p}+h^{2/p}+i^{3/p}+j^{4/p}$$
I follow that F/G can be expressed in that  way (always), but
$1.$***how does that prove his claim in*** ($1$)?
(Here R is an algebraic function.)

2.He then substitutes $(1)$ in $(2)$ and gets$$k+lR^{1/p}+mR^{2/p}+nR^{3/p}+oR^{4/p}=0$$
his next claim is that $$l=m=n=o=0$$
**How** ?
3.Abel observes that if $y$<sub>0</sub> is a solution to $$y^5-ay^4+by^3-cY^2+dy-e=0$$
so are the values of $y$<sub>i</sub> where $y$<sub>i</sub> are obtained by multiplying $y$<sub>0</sub> with 5<sup>th</sup> root of unity.
**How?**

Comment: Maybe useful : Jeremy Gray, [A history of abstract algebra From algebraic equations to modern algebra (Springer, 2018)](https://books.google.it/books?id=gl1oDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA97), **Ch.9.3 The Unsolvability of the Quintic: Abel’s Work**, page 99-on.